# How to access the variable range for leaf node in classregtree of matlab?

Tags: matlab, tree

I used classregtree to fit a tree to my data set in order to classify the data. All of predictors and the response are quantitative. I want to save the range of each variable on terminal nodes, because I am gonna use those ranges in another function.
So is there any way that I can have access to those ranges? I can see the variable ranges in view(tree) plot but I need to save them in like a matrix to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure that this is what you were asking for but this gives you the split criterions for all trees

```
B = TreeBagger(nTrees,M,tag, 'Method', 'classification','OOBPred','on');
view(B.Trees{1:B.NTrees})
```

where M is your trainig data set and tag are the classes.